# How can I convert these dates to the correct format in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with some dates and I want to convert them to datetime format. So I used the `pd.to_datetime` function to do so. However, it only works for some of the dates as the others are not written in the correct order. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates' : ['December 2021 17', '2005 July 01', 'December 2000 01', '2008 May 11', 
                              'October 2000 04', 'September 2016 04', 'May 1998 09']})
```

Using `pd.to_datetime` will only return values for the `yy-mm-dd` order. I tried splitting these into list and tried to reorder them, but that didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` and give it `to_datetime`:

```
df.dates = df.dates.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

This is the output of `df` now:

```
       dates
0 2021-12-17
1 2005-07-01
2 2000-12-01
3 2008-05-11
4 2000-10-04
5 2016-09-04
6 1998-05-09
```

Comment: Thanks! What does apply do here exactly?

Comment: `apply` applies a function - in this case `pd.to_datetime` - to the column `dates`. You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract the year, month and date

```
y = df['dates'].str.extract(r'(?P<year>\b\d{4}\b)',expand=False) 
d = df['dates'].str.extract(r'(?P<day>\b\d{2}\b)',expand = False) 
m = df['dates'].str.extract(r'(?P<month>\b[A-Za-z]+\b)',expand = False)

pd.to_datetime(y.str.cat([m,d]),format = '%Y%B%d')
```

Output:

```
0   2021-12-17
1   2005-07-01
2   2000-12-01
3   2008-05-11
4   2000-10-04
5   2016-09-04
6   1998-05-09
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable using `apply` function (functional programming) as suggested by @Marcelo Paco, you may try this.

Let your dataframe is called `date_df`. You can convert the `dates` column to your desired format as follows;

```
import pandas as pd


date_df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(date_df['dates'])
date_df
```

Output:

```
    dates
0   2021-12-17
1   2005-07-01
2   2000-12-01
3   2008-05-11
4   2000-10-04
5   2016-09-04
6   1998-05-09
```