# How to convert string to date format in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working with a data frame on unemployment stats and the date is in format as 2010 AUG, 2018 DEC. I would like to convert it to date format and to include the last day of the month, 2010-31-08 or 08/31/2010. I can't use pd.to_datetime if the month is in string using letters instead of numbers right?

I can only seem to find info on how to convert when the format is using numbers. Will I need to manually change JAN to 01, FEB to 02 etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert these dates to the correct format in a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75710856/how-can-i-convert-these-dates-to-the-correct-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_string'], format='mixed') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)`

Answer (score 0):

## Convert String to Date

You can still convert the date string to a datetime object using the `datetime.strptime()` function from the built-in `datetime` module in Python.

Here's an example code to convert your date string to a datetime object with the last day of the month:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_string': ['2010 AUG', '2018 DEC']})

# define a function to convert date strings to datetime objects with last day of month
def convert_date(date_string):
    # convert month name to number
    month_num = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y %b').month
    # get the last day of the month
    last_day = pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y %b').replace(day=1) \
                           + pd.DateOffset(months=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=1))
    # combine year, month, and day to create datetime object
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(f"{date_string.split(' ')[0]}-{month_num:02d}-{last_day.day:02d}", '%Y-%m-%d')
    return datetime_obj

# apply the function to the 'date_string' column to create a new 'date' column
df['date'] = df['date_string'].apply(convert_date)

# print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Output will be:

```
  date_string       date
0     2010 AUG 2010-08-31
1     2018 DEC 2018-12-31
```

### Explanation

1. Create a sample DataFrame with a column of date strings in
   the format of **YYYY MON**.
2. Then, define a function `convert_date()` that takes a date string as input, converts the month name to its corresponding number using `datetime.strptime()`, gets the last day of the month using `pd.Timestamp()`, and combines the year, month, and day to create a datetime object.
3. Then apply this function to the 'date_string' column using the `apply()` method to create a new 'date' column with datetime objects.
4. Print the resulting `DataFrame`.